# Is it possible to capture the backspace or left and right arrow keys in COBOL?

Tags: keyboard, cobol

I want to capture the arrow keystrokes using the `ACCEPT` statement. I now have this:

```
ACCEPT MY-DUMMY
    CONTROL KEY IN MY-KEYSTROKE
```

and this is working for the up and down arrow. For the left and right arrows, however, it won't work, because those keys are used by the runtime to navigate within the input field.

Is there any way to capture those keystrokes for only this `ACCEPT`, and prevent the host to consume them?

- Compiler: **ACUCOBOL-GT** (I don't know which version or release yet)
- Operating system: **Windows 10**

---

In addition to the accepted answer:

One can prepend the exception code to the exception key to distinguish left and right arrow keystrokes.

```
SET ENVIRONMENT "KEYSTROKE" TO "EXCEPTION=054,Left kl"
SET ENVIRONMENT "KEYSTROKE" TO "EXCEPTION=055,Right kr"
SET ENVIRONMENT "KEYSTROKE" TO "EXCEPTION=201,BkSp ZB"

ACCEPT DUMMY
    CONTROL KEY IN MY-KEYSTROKE
EVALUATE (MY-KEYSTROKE)
    WHEN 054
        PERFORM DO-SOMETHING
END-EVALUATE
```

Comment: Which compiler and version are you using?  Which OS?

Comment: Answer: yes it is...
If you want to know how to do it.. it heavily depends on the compiler used you have to go different paths. ACUCOBOL let you set keystrokes which map to function keys, if you use the cursor values you should get them back, too. Other vendors have different extensions.
If you only need a single keypress and have access to C library something like `CALL 'getch'` (if the system uses curses) may even be the better option.

Comment: I've added the exception key to the answer. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ACUCOBOL (quoted from [ACUCOBOL runtime manual](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.extendACUSuite%2FGUID-B7CDDA80-A84C-45AA-9965-44752A180780.html&cp=5_0_1_4_8_0_6))

> By default, the left and right arrows act as edit keys, and the up and down arrows act as both edit and exception keys. You can change the behavior of the arrows at run time to switch between different modes if you need to. You do this via the `SET ENVIRONMENT` verb and the appropriate `KEYSTROKE` settings.

```
SET ENVIRONMENT "KEYSTROKE" TO "EXCEPTION=055,Left kl"
SET ENVIRONMENT "KEYSTROKE" TO "EXCEPTION=056,Right kr"
ACCEPT OMITTED   CONTROL KEY IN MY-KEYSTROKE
SET ENVIRONMENT "KEYSTROKE" TO "EDIT=Left kl"
SET ENVIRONMENT "KEYSTROKE" TO "EDIT=Right kr"
```

See also [ACUCOBOL User Guide, key table](https://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/AcucorpProducts/docs/v6_online_doc/gtman1/gt1418.htm).

BTW: "Newer" ACUCOBOL versions (read as "not completely outdated") support `ACCEPT OMITTED`.